# Add smooth transition on image swap

Tags: jquery

I have a small image gallery with thumbnails and a main window for the enlarged image. When you click the thumbnails, they appear in the window, so fully functional, however I would like to add a smooth fading in/out transition, rather than just a sudden swap, however I am not sure how to do this.

Here is the codepen... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uatGg

My current jQuery code...

```
$('.thumbnails .zoom').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var photo_fullsize =  $(this).find('img').attr('src');

  $('.woocommerce-main-image img').attr('src', photo_fullsize);

});
```

I have tried using fadeIn and fadeOut, but I do not want the image to fade out (show white background), then fade the new image in. I would like the image to fade in on top of the current image, so the background is never visible on transition.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fade effects from jQuery:

```
$('.woocommerce-main-image img').hide().attr('src', photo_fullsize).fadeIn();
```

See the [jQuery docs for more options](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/).

If this causes some unwanted HTML wrapping effects from the image getting hidden, you could also put the `a.woocommerce-main-image` zoom element in a wrapper div with a set height and width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried this using fadeIn and out, but this fades out first (you get the white background) and then fades in. I was looking for a solution that fades into the new image. I will make that clearer in my post